# Why does fstrim not seem to be thorough?

Tags: ssd, trim

I tried the command `fstrim` to manually TRIM my SSD drive, i.e. to discard unused blocks.

I know this is done automatically by a weekly cronjob, but I wanted to try it myself once.

However, running the command in verbose mode multiple times immediately one after the other, not only the first but also quite many of the subsequent calls still discard a rather big amount of blocks.

The system is otherwise on idle, there should not be much (if any) disk activity between those calls.

Here's an example, I called the command about once per second:

```
$ sudo fstrim -va
/: 13,3 GiB (14308057088 bytes) trimmed
$ sudo fstrim -va
/: 507,2 MiB (531845120 bytes) trimmed
$ sudo fstrim -va
/: 113 MiB (118448128 bytes) trimmed
$ sudo fstrim -va
/: 0 B (0 bytes) trimmed
$ sudo fstrim -va
/: 0 B (0 bytes) trimmed
$ sudo fstrim -va
/: 0 B (0 bytes) trimmed
$ sudo fstrim -va
/: 0 B (0 bytes) trimmed
$ sudo fstrim -va
/: 190,6 MiB (199856128 bytes) trimmed
$ sudo fstrim -va
/: 0 B (0 bytes) trimmed
$ sudo fstrim -va
/: 0 B (0 bytes) trimmed
$ sudo fstrim -va
/: 0 B (0 bytes) trimmed
$ sudo fstrim -va
/: 0 B (0 bytes) trimmed
$ sudo fstrim -va
/: 0 B (0 bytes) trimmed
$ sudo fstrim -va
/: 0 B (0 bytes) trimmed
$ sudo fstrim -va
/: 0 B (0 bytes) trimmed
$ sudo fstrim -va
/: 68,2 MiB (71479296 bytes) trimmed
$ sudo fstrim -va
/: 0 B (0 bytes) trimmed
```

Is the `fstrim` command not thorough or why do subsequent calls still discard blocks?

Answer (score 2):

This may be because dirty data is still being flushed back to the device or because background processes (such as logging daemons) etc are writing to the device. A good experiment would be to force dirty data to be sync'd back to the device before trying the trim using `sync`.